# How to get Custom Error Pages working for Classic ASP with IIS 7 Integrated Pipeline

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, asp-classic, custom-errors, integrated-pipeline-mode

I'm working on a website with legacy Classic ASP pages (being converted to ASP.NET on an as needed basis) and new ASP.NET pages. Use of IIS 7 Integrated Pipeline has been very helpful with our configuration. For example, we were able to get forms authentication working auto-magically with the classic ASP pages simply by configuring the appropriate sections of the web.config file (i.e. no changes were required to the Classic ASP pages, for more info see [this](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/244/how-to-take-advantage-of-the-iis7-integrated-pipeline/)).

A colleague of mine believes that custom error pages, as specified in the web.config <customErrors> section, should also be auto-magically applied to the classic ASP pages, but for our website it only works for the ASP.NET pages. Nor have I been able to find any information describing the capability of applying custom error pages to Classic ASP with the IIS 7 integrated pipeline.

Is it possible to apply custom error pages to Classic ASP pages per a web.config for an website running under IIS7 with integrated pipeline? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IIS7 custom error pages are handled in the `<system.webServer>` configuration section not the `<customErrors>` section under `<system.web>` which applies to ASP.NET only:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors>
            <error 
               statusCode="500" 
               subStatusCode="100" 
               path="/500errors.asp" 
               responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Beware though of these settings conflicting with ASP.NET custom errors. If you're running .NET 3.5 and above you can set [`Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.tryskipiiscustomerrors%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) in your ASP.NET error page code-behind (or error controller if using MVC) to prevent IIS overriding your ASP.NET error page(s):

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true // ASP.NET Forms
```

This article by Rick Strahl explains this problem in a bit more depth:

> [IIS 7 Error Pages taking over 500 Errors](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/745738.aspx)

Comment: This is very helpful information. One question, is there a way to not have to specify statusCode, say, to specify what page to use as a default?

Comment: @harrije - you can set `defaultPath` on `<httpErrors>`. For more info see: http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpErrors